# How do I take apart a modern Silca Impero frame pump?

Tags: maintenance, pump

I have a new frame pump and I want to take it apart. All the way - down to the metal tubes. This is the top of the air chamber and I don't know how to proceed. There is no trim piece covering this and the top of the tube isn't threaded. How is this opened? It should be simple as the leather valve in this pump is a serviceable part.

Also how does the head come off the other end? It doesn't seem to screw on (and unless I'm sure I don't want to apply any more force)

[image: Silca Impero frame pump]

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with the exact pump, and I'm not going to question why you want to strip down your brand new pump, but I can help you remove that fastener. It's a snap ring that is made of flexible spring steel and sits in a groove.

1. Cover the shaft with a paper towel or something. Secure it well. You don't want to scratch it by accident if a tool slips or something.
2. Get a small flat head screwdriver or other similar tool and use it to hold the flat end of the ring in place.
3. With your other hand, while keeping tension on the flat end of the ring to hold it, use another small screwdriver to push that small notch towards the center.
4. You can then push that end of the ring up and out of the slot it resides in. Work your way around to lift and remove the rest of the ring. It should eventually all come out of the slot.

Comment: So its a special interior circlip ?

Comment: @Criggie I wouldn't say it's special - for example, my ratchet wrenches are held together with clips of this type. I suppose they're cheaper to make and less user friendly (encourages the purchase of a new pump vs a normal style circlip with easy-to-use circlip pliers).

Comment: yeah that was my point - it lacks the two little eyelets used by normal circlip pliers, which makes it special (ie, awkward)

Comment: Could these eyelets be missing on purpose to prevent users from taking the pump apart?

Comment: This particular pump uses leather gaskets, rather than the rubber o-rings that everyone else uses. The gaskets may be very durable in the long term, but they do require periodic lubrication, and I'm pretty sure the manufacturer says so, and they sell an appropriate lube. So the OP may not need to take their pump apart *right now*, but they should eventually. In any case, Silca does explicitly design their pumps to be serviceable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Silca pumps are entirely serviceable. I have been in touch with them and they've supplied diagrams confirming the information from MaplePanda. They are also often commonly painted. That's my reason - I'm trying to match the pump to my frame so I need the tubes separated.

Comment: The company just released a YouTube video corroborating the assertion that you just use a small flat head screwdriver to get the circlip off. The bit specifically about the circlip starts around 2:20. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHs4uTW4uJE